# What is the request structure of sending a message using facebook php sdk version 4?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I tried the getting started example provided by Facebook, they worked and returned results.

i want to send a message but i keep getting the Unsupported post request error.

in the old sdk i used to do it like this

```
$r = $facebook->api("/" . $facebook_inbox_id . '/messages', 'POST', array('access_token'=>$token, 'message'=>$message_text));
```

here is my code which i have a problem with

```
$path    = "/590340984336945/messages/";
     $msg     = 'new msg';
     try{
         if($session){
             $response = (new FacebookRequest(
               $session, 'POST', $path, array(
                 'message'=>$msg,
               )
               ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

             print_R($response);
         }
     }catch(\Facebook\FacebookRequestException $ex){
         die($ex->getMessage());
     }
```

i have a valid access token in the session.

can someone tell me what's the problem, or what is the equivalent of sending a msg in the older SDKs in the new one?

found out i must prefix this     $path    = "/590340984336945/messages/"; with '/v2.0'

now I'm getting Unknown path components error.

edit: i was using facebook as a page not as a user. and wanted to send a message from the page to a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use an extended token and everything worked well.

I don't know why so many posts on the internet saying that you can't use the api to send a message. i was doing it in the old api and now the new one.

code for sending a message when using facebook as a page to a user:

```
        \Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app_id','secret');
         $session = new \Facebook\FacebookSession("$token");
         $msg = 'hello world'!;

         try{
             if($session){
                 //make an api call to create a new reply for a message
                 $result = (new FacebookRequest(
                   $session, 'POST', '/' . $fbInboxId . '/messages', array(
                     'message'=>$msg,
                   )
                   ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
          }catch(Exception $e){}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how you managed to send a message using the API, when only reading the mailbox is supported. [Both v1.0 and v2.0 do not support publishing to Threads](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/thread) (i.e. support sending of messages via the API).

Sending a message must be done using the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog).

Comment: i still have the application running, i am sure i can send messages, i was using php sdk 2.0. is sending messages deprecated in the latter ones? @Niraj Shah

Comment: Yes, the ability to send messages was removed a while back, so the newer APIs no longer support it.

Comment: oh, do you have any references for that? @Niraj Shah

Comment: I can't find where it was depreciated, but the documentation link I provided in the answer shows that you cannot publish anymore.

Comment: hello again, i just want to tell you that i was able to solve this, you CAN send messages via the api, i had to use an extended token and everything worked as before.

Comment: Please review this answer, the above seems to show this as wrong?